# Flutter GTK 3.0 and 'libjpeg' not found

Tags: flutter, gtk3

Flutter was just working great, I install brew on Ubuntu 22.04 to install `bundletool`. Then one compiling for linux I get gtk not found, here what I tried so far:

## From `flutter doctor`:

> **✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.**

For this in the terminal I tried:

1. `sudo apt install  libgtk-3-dev` and it was already installed, so reinstalled it.
2. `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` and got: `3.24.34`.
3. `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`, got this:

```
-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.34/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/pango/1.50.8/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/harfbuzz/5.1.0/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/atk/2.38.0/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.42.8_1/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

So I think I've no problem with gtk, though I removed it totally and inspected it using `synaptic` but the problem presists.

## Inside VS Code when compiling I get:

> A required package was not found Package

and that's from `cmake`, so I tinkered with the line that produced the error to figure out which package, and with printing: `_pkgconfig_error`, I got: `'libjpeg', required by 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0', not found`.

Again went through the whole thing using `synaptic` reinstalling, and `dpkg -l | grep libjpeg` gives:

```
ii  libjpeg-dev:amd64                                 8c-2ubuntu10                                         amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg-progs                                     1:9d-1                                               amd64        Programs for manipulating JPEG files
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64                              2.1.2-0ubuntu1                                       amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:i386                               2.1.2-0ubuntu1                                       i386         IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64                          2.1.2-0ubuntu1                                       amd64        Development files for the IJG JPEG library
ii  libjpeg8:amd64                                    8c-2ubuntu10                                         amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg8:i386                                     8c-2ubuntu10                                         i386         Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg8-dev:amd64                                8c-2ubuntu10                                         amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg9:amd64                                    1:9d-1                                               amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library
```

Running `flutter run -d linux -v` outputs this:

```
[  +77 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +37 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +9 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git tag --points-at f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[  +21 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[        ] 3.0.5
[  +14 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +146 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +20 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +76 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +110 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +135 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +256 ms] Generating
/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +212 ms] Initializing file store
[  +18 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +13 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have
updated contents: /media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/.dart_tool/package_config_subset}
[  +68 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[   +8 ms] Skipping target: _composite
[   +2 ms] complete
[  +11 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
[  +10 ms] /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/opt/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter
--debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill
/tmp/flutter_tools.PZDYPM/flutter_tool.QVKDFK/app.dill --packages
/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/.dart_tool/package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill
build/c075001b96339384a97db4862b8ab8db.cache.dill.track.dill --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
[  +54 ms] Building Linux application...
[  +35 ms] <- compile package:cstore/main.dart
[   +3 ms] executing: [build/linux/x64/debug/] cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DFLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM=linux-x64 /media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/linux
[ +148 ms] -- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
[   +3 ms] --   Package 'libjpeg', required by 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0', not found
[   +9 ms] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[        ] See also "/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[   +2 ms] CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
[   +3 ms]   A required package was not found Package 'libjpeg', required by
[        ]   'gdk-pixbuf-2.0', not found
[        ] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[        ]   /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
[        ]   flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)
[  +30 ms] Building Linux application... (completed in 225ms)
[+11062 ms] Exception: Unable to generate build files
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 12,254ms.
[   +7 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
```

CMakeOutput.log content:

```
The system is: Linux - 5.15.0-43-generic - x86_64
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is Clang, found in "/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_df355 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
Homebrew clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 (in-process)
 "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/clang-14" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -resource-dir /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6 -dependency-file CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o.d -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -sys-header-deps -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward -internal-isystem /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -x c++ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward
 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_df355
Homebrew clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTC_df355 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtend.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o



Parsed CXX implicit include dir info from above output: rv=done
  found start of include info
  found start of implicit include info
    add: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11]
    add: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11]
    add: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward]
    add: [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include]
    add: [/usr/local/include]
    add: [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    add: [/usr/include]
  end of search list found
  collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11] ==> [/usr/include/c++/11]
  collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11] ==> [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11]
  collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward] ==> [/usr/include/c++/11/backward]
  collapse include dir [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include] ==> [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include]
  collapse include dir [/usr/local/include] ==> [/usr/local/include]
  collapse include dir [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse include dir [/usr/include] ==> [/usr/include]
  implicit include dirs: [/usr/include/c++/11;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11;/usr/include/c++/11/backward;/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include;/usr/local/include;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu;/usr/include]


Parsed CXX implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld\.lld|CMAKE_LINK_STARTFILE-NOTFOUND|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_df355 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o]
  ignore line: [Homebrew clang version 14.0.6]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [InstalledDir: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
  ignore line: [Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
  ignore line: [Candidate multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  ignore line: [Selected multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  ignore line: [ (in-process)]
  ignore line: [ "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/clang-14" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -resource-dir /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6 -dependency-file CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o.d -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -sys-header-deps -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward -internal-isystem /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -x c++ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp]
  ignore line: [clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"]
  ignore line: [#include "..." search starts here:]
  ignore line: [#include <...> search starts here:]
  ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11]
  ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11]
  ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward]
  ignore line: [ /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib/clang/14.0.6/include]
  ignore line: [ /usr/local/include]
  ignore line: [ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [ /usr/include]
  ignore line: [End of search list.]
  ignore line: [[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_df355]
  ignore line: [Homebrew clang version 14.0.6]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [InstalledDir: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
  ignore line: [Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
  ignore line: [Candidate multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  ignore line: [Selected multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  link line: [ "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTC_df355 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtend.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
    arg [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-zrelro] ==> ignore
    arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
    arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
    arg [-m] ==> ignore
    arg [elf_x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTC_df355] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o] ==> obj [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o]
    arg [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o] ==> obj [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbegin.o] ==> obj [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbegin.o]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64]
    arg [-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/../lib64] ==> dir [/lib/../lib64]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/../lib64] ==> dir [/usr/lib/../lib64]
    arg [-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/../lib] ==> dir [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/../lib]
    arg [-L/lib] ==> dir [/lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib]
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTC_df355.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lstdc++] ==> lib [stdc++]
    arg [-lm] ==> lib [m]
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [-lc] ==> lib [c]
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtend.o] ==> obj [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtend.o]
    arg [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o] ==> obj [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64] ==> [/usr/lib64]
  collapse library dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/../lib64] ==> [/lib64]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/../lib64] ==> [/usr/lib64]
  collapse library dir [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/../lib] ==> [/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib]
  collapse library dir [/lib] ==> [/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib] ==> [/usr/lib]
  implicit libs: [stdc++;m;gcc_s;gcc;c;gcc_s;gcc]
  implicit objs: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o;/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbegin.o;/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtend.o;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
  implicit dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11;/usr/lib64;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib64;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/lib;/lib;/usr/lib]
  implicit fwks: []
```

So far I'm tired with this, don't have a clue on what's going on wrong! Everything is there, also I restarted a ton.

Comment: does it print any other stuff if you run `flutter run -d Linux -v`? here `-v` stands for "verbose"

Comment: It mentions `Package 'libjpeg', required by 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0', not found` which I mentioned before.
I updated the question with it's full output, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: and is anything interesting in /media/mrt/Data/CODE/FLUTTER/cstore/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log ?

Comment: I added `CMakeOutput.log`'s file content to the question, take a look and see if you notice something.

Comment: hmm nothing interesting I guess :-(, as soon as I get home I will check what libjpeg related packages I have

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally fixed it, I noticed in `CMakeOutput.log` file that clang comes from Homebrew, it override installed one. Ended up with me uninstalling `brew` as whole, I think I could have found a way to retain to the original clang installation but removing the alien was cleaner.

Comment: so, CMakeOutput.log was still helpful :-)

Comment: Yup, it was all there. Thanks dude :-)

Comment: Uninstall Homebrew (brute force solution...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) comment I noticed that `Homebrew` overrides `clang` installation, so I removed `brew` and all it's fuss as a cleaner option, and installed clang again: `sudo apt install clang`. Done.

Thanks [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink).